# 3705 operation is not allowed when the object is open

Tags: database, excel, vba

I have some data in an Excel form and I want to import it into database. I also want to retrieve some data from database. I am using VBA for connecting to database it my code is giving me an error.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()


   Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset


       'Open a connection to SQL Server
       conn.Provider = "sqloledb"
       conn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
       conn.Open "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=bank;"

       'conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ASUSBOOK\SQL2012;Initial Catalog=ExcelDemo;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
       Set rs.ActiveConnection = conn
           rs.Open "select code from info"
           startrow = 2

           Do Until rs.EOF
           Cells(startrow, 5) = rs.Fields(0).Value


           rs.MoveNext
           startrow = startrow + 1

           Loop

           rs.Close
           Set rs = Nothing


    Dim iRowNo As Integer
    Dim accountno, Amount, code As String
    Dim Rowcount As Integer
    Rowcount = 1


    With Sheets("Sheet1")


        iRowNo = 2

            Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
            accountno = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
            Amount = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
            .Cells(iRowNo, 3) = "OK"
            .Cells(iRowNo, 4) = Rowcount
            .Cells(iRowNo, 5) = Post_Date

            'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table
            conn.Provider = "sqloledb"
            conn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
            conn.Open "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=bank;"
            conn.Execute "insert into dbo.Customers (AccountNo,Amount,code) values ('" & accountno & "', '" & Amount & "', '" & code & "')"

            iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
            Rowcount = Rowcount + 1
            DoEvents

        Loop

        MsgBox "Customers imported."

        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing

    End With




End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error you get and which line is responsible for it?

Comment: You didn't close `conn` before trying to reset its properties.

Comment: this line is responsible conn.provider="sqloledb" 
and error is 3705 operation is not allowed when the object is open Lajo Arpad

Comment: when i close conn  of first code is run and show error operation is not allowed when the object is open  Roy

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow that at all.

Answer (score 0):

Set the CursorLocation property of the ADO Recordset to `adUseClient`:

```
conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
```